# How do I put source code into subfolders in VB6?

Tags: vb6, package

I have all the forms in one folder and all the code modules in an other folder in VB6. How do I create a better folder structure for the source files?

For example if I have twenty forms and twenty code modules, how can I create subfolders Main, Sales, and Employees and put the source files under those subfolders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should investigate whether some of your files could reside in a ActiveX DLL instead of the main EXE project. As Konrad pointed out the VB6 IDE project explorer doesn't support folders. Large VB6 projects, like my own, organize the classes into a hierarchy of ActiveX DLLs. For example Utility DLL which has commonly used routines used across the company's applications (file handling, etc). Business Object DLL which has the specific classes used by your applications. Report DLL has the classes that handles reports for that applications. And so on.

The gotcha is that you have to worry about compatibility issues between versions.

Answer (score 5):

You can (and should) create subfolders in the file system to organize your files. However, this hierarchy will not be mirrored by the VB6 project explorer, which basically provides a flat hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

well if you're talking about adding a new folder from vb6 project explorer view,
i'm not sure that you can do so.

but if you want to sort it you can apply some naming convention, i.e. module1_xxx, module1_yyy.